# Maximum speed of loopback sockets

Tags: performance, kernel, benchmarking, netcat

`pv /dev/zero| nc -l 1234` and `nc localhost 1234 > /dev/null`

give me a maximum throughput of around 430 MB/s. **Why is that?**

`htop` shows mostly kernel CPU activity, so my suspicion so far is kernel-to-user space copying.

Are there ways to get higher throughputs than this or does this mean that **no network program can ever achieve > 500 MB/s** throughput (at least on this machine)?

Comment: Depends on your hardware.  If you really need something faster than that, use memory mapped io.